# Re-Bind UDP socket

Tags: visual-c++, winsock

I made a program that send messages out using udp. The program will initially initialize the udp socket with a default ip address and port. However, it should also allow users to change the destination ip address and port during runtime.

Currently, I close the current socket if the users change the ip address/port, and re initialize/bind the socket with the new ip address/port.

The program is able to send out the messages successfully with the initial socket. But when I rebind the ip address/port, the binding sometimes failed. Bind() return a value of -1. I did some search online and read that TCP protocol has a 2msl timeout when a socket is close. Does that apply to UDP?

Also, is there a better method to allow user to change the destination ip/port. I'm using C++ on visual studio btw.

Thanks.

Comment: When `bind()` fails, what is the return value of `WSAGetLastError()`?

Answer (score 0):

The 2MSI timeout does not apply to UDP.  However, it is possible that another app is using the ip/port you are trying to bind to.  If you know the ip/port is safe to use, you can use `setsockopt()` to enable the socket's `SO_REUSEADDR` option before calling `bind()`.

Comment: Sorry, can't really copy and paste my code here, as I am working on a confidential project. Project is done on a com with no internet access and data transfer between PC is not allowed.

Comment: WSAGetLastError returns a value of 10022 when Bind() is called. Tried using SO_REUSEADDR. The problem still exists.

Comment: 10022 is `WSAEINVAL`, which `bind()` returns if the socket is already bound to an address. A socket can only be bound once.